# escape delimiter between date fileds while using sed

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

I'm trying to remove delimiter `|` with in the quotes using sed on text which contains dates, nulls, strings with pipe delimiter. I used following sed its working fine but its removing delimiter between dates. Any help will be appreciated.

```
sed -E 's/(^|[^"|])\|($|[^"|])/\1 \2/g' <file>
```

Input:

```
"Southern|Palms"|"AA|None"|"4"|"Ken|Coast"|1/11/2019 00:00:00|30/4/2020 00:00:00|"TH"|
```

Returns:

`"Southern Palms"|"AA None"|"4"|"Ken Coast"|1/11/2019 00:00:00 30/4/2020 00:00:00|"TH"|`

Expected Output:
`"Southern Palms"|"AA None"|"4"|"Ken Coast"|1/11/2019 00:00:00|30/4/2020 00:00:00|"TH"|`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
sed -E 's/(\w+)\|(\w+)/\1 \2/g' testfile.txt
```

\w+\|\w+ matches pipe symbols between two words like this `<word1>|<word2>` and replaces it with the two words separated by a space like this `<word1> <word2>`

If you want to match the quotes use:

```
sed -E 's/("\w+)\|(\w+")/\1 \2/g' testfile.txt
```

That matches `"<word1>|<word2>"` and replaces it with `"<word1> <word2>"`

Comment: delimiter is missing between date fields with above sed

Comment: @marjun I ran it on my Linux machine with the input you provided and I got the output that you said is expected. That's with quotes in the pattern by way.

Comment: its answer my quotient, what if a delimiter in between  multiple words "Southern Palms|Beach Resort"

Comment: This fails if there are more than two words within the quotes like this: `"Southern|Palms|spring"|"AA|None"|"4"`

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for FPAT:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[^|]*|"[^"]+"' -v OFS='|' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) gsub(/\|+/," ",$i)} 1' file
"Southern Palms"|"AA None"|"4"|"Ken Coast"|1/11/2019 00:00:00|30/4/2020 00:00:00|"TH"|
```

See [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk)

Comment: i tried above awk but its replacing space with delimiter "UK|&|I" "KEKE0006" "Southern Palms Beach|Resort" "AA|None" "4" "Kenya" "MBA" "Kenyan|Coast" "Y" 1/11/2019|00:00:00 30/4/2020|00:00:00

Comment: It does exactly what you asked for. If you're seeing unexpected output then you either copy/pasted the script wrong or your real input doesn't look like your expected output or you aren't running gawk. What does running `awk --version` tell you?

Comment: its having GNU Awk 3.1.7

Comment: That is an **extremely** archaic version of gawk (5+ years out of date) that pre-dates FPAT. We're currently on gawk 5.0.2 - can you update your version? You're missing a TON of extremely useful functionality and some bug fixes.